# How to create a new column containing the largest value in a list that is smaller than cell value in an existing column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like:

```
     a   
0    0   
1   -2  
2    4  
3    1  
4    6
```

I also have a list

```
A = [-1, 2, 5, 7]
```

I want to add a new column called 'b', that contains the largest value in A that is smaller than the cell value in column 'a'. If no such value exists, I want the value in 'b' to be 'X'. So, the goal is to get:

```
    a   b
0   0  -1
1  -2   X
2   4   2
3   1  -1
4   6   5
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: What if no such element exists? What should `b` contain?

Comment: I've edited the question, thanks!

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic. Provide a [mcve] of what you tried and explain where your problems with it are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a build-in function `merge_asof`

```
s=pd.DataFrame({'a':A,'b':A})

pd.merge_asof(df.assign(index=df.index).sort_values('a'),s,on='a').set_index('index').sort_index().fillna('X')
Out[284]: 
       a  b
index      
0      0 -1
1     -2  X
2      4  2
3      1 -1
4      6  5
```

Comment: This will find the closest element (small or large), not the closest smaller one.

Answer (score 2):

```
def largest_min(x):
    less_than = list(filter(lambda l: l < x, A))

    if len(less_than):
       return max(less_than)

    return 'X'

df['b'] = df['a'].apply(largest_min)
```

edited: To fix error and and 'X' for no values found

Answer (score 2):

Not sure of a `pandas` method, but [`numpy.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) is a perfect fit here.

> Finds indices where elements should be inserted to maintain order.

Once you have the indices that your elements would be inserted into to maintain the sort, you can look at the element to the *left* of these indices in your lookup array to find the closest smaller element.  If the element would be inserted at the beginning of the list (index 0), we know that a smaller element does not exist in the lookup list, and we account for that scenario using `np.where`

---

```
A = np.array([-1, 2, 5, 7])
r = np.searchsorted(A, df.a.values)

df.assign(b=np.where(r == 0, np.nan, A[r-1])).fillna('X')
```

```
   a  b
0  0 -1
1 -2  X
2  4  2
3  1 -1
4  6  5
```

---

This method will be much faster than `apply` here.

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10_000)

%%timeit
r = np.searchsorted(A, df.a.values)
df.assign(b=np.where(r == 0, np.nan, A[r-1])).fillna('X')
6.09 ms ± 367 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df['a'].apply(largest_min)
196 ms ± 5.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it as well:

```
df1 = pd.Series(A)

def filler(val):
    v = df1[df1 < val.iloc[0]].max()
    return v

df.assign(b=df.apply(filler, axis=1).fillna('X'))

   a  b
0  0 -1
1 -2  X
2  4  2
3  1 -1
4  6  5
```

Answer (score -1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,4,1,6]})
A = [-1,2,5,7]

new_list = []
for i in df.iterrows():
    for j in range(len(A)):
        if A[j] < i[1]['a']:
            print(A[j])
            pass
        elif j == 0:
            new_list.append(A[j])
            break
        else:
            new_list.append(A[j-1])
            break

df['b'] = new_list
```

Comment: avoid `iterrows` if possible in `pandas` it defeats the purpose